# Resolving blurred scanner compact disc album artwork

Tags: images, blur, scanning

I wonder if anyone can help with an annoying problem I have when scanning parts of the artwork of albums on compact disc.

If the CD is packaged in a cardboard sleeve, often it is held in place using clear plastic.  Sometimes, beneath this plastic, there is artwork, e.g:

[image]

As you can see though, the text here is distorted.

I have tried scanning for `.jpg` or `.png` files as output and using various `dpi` up to 600. But the effect is the same.

Can anyone suggest why this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to do this if you want quality scans is **to remove the paper from the plastic** and scan the paper, not the jewel case. You *can* pry open the jewel case base to get the sleeve out, just be careful not to break the case.

The "blur" happens because the text is too far away from the flatbed scanner surface.

---

If the sleeve is **glued** to the base... then there may be nothing you can really do about the blur. You *might* have better luck taking a good **photograph** of the base rather than trying to scan it. Flatbed scanners inherently don't work with depth well.

Comment: I appreciate that but with jewel cases there is no problem because the plastic holding the disc can be detached. Unfortunately, that is not the case with digipacks where the plastic is fixed directly to the sleeve.

Comment: Admittedly it's been ... oh.... a decade or more .... since I've purchased any CD/DVD... but every single case I've seen can be opened. if you mean the sleeve is *glued* to the base... then there may be nothing you can really do about it. You *might* have better luck taking a good *photograph* of the base rather than scanning it. Flatbed scanners simply don't work with depth well at all.

Comment: In the case in point in the graphic supplied, the plastic case is fixed to the sleeve. Sometimes, you can see the marks of the glue used for fixing.

Comment: @MrMorgan -Notice how the dust on the cover is in perfect focus, but the text is not.  That is because a scanner can't focus on anything that is not directly on the surface of the glass.  It will not work. Maybe use a camera instead if you can't get the copy out of the CD case.

Comment: @BillyKerr, did you have to mention the dust? 

Comment: Some of these CD labels can be found online as pictures.

Comment: @Lucien: Yes on websites like https://www.discogs.com  but I have checked for this one and it is not there.

Comment: re: photograph, you'd want to use a tripod and a small aperture (e.g f16) to widen the focus depth.

Comment: I'd go with the photograph approach. Modern cameras have enough pixel density to get good quality "scans"

Comment: @Yorik I'd use a wide aperture and manually focus on the text, to (slightly) soften the focus on the clip in the middle

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Google Photo Scan app](https://www.google.com/photos/scan/) to "scan" the picture into digital form.

I've used it for physical photos and it has done quite a good job compared to a scanner.